# Config.xml not configured properly

Tags: cordova

I'm attempting to create a new project using cordova/phonegap.  I was able to successfully install cordova and phonegap.

```
$ phonegap -v
3.6.3-0.22.6
$cordova -v
4.1.2
```

I am able to create a new project

```
phonegap create sample
```

When I inspect the project contents, I do not see a second config.xml under ./www.  I only see the config.xml under the root folder.

- **Has the second config.xml been removed? If not, why am I not seeing the second config.xml and how do I create it?**

When I add additional platforms/plugins whether through `cordova plugins add` or `phonegap plugins add`, I do not see any changes in the config.xml.

- **Am I supposed to be managing everything in the config.xml?  If not, why is the config.xml not being updated and what do I need to do to fix it?**

Specifically, I am trying to add the `com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner` and it is not appearing in the config.xml.  However, I did notice that all of the standard cordova plugins were listed.

- **If I do not need a certain feature such as `org.apache.cordova.contacts`, is it safe just to remove it from the list?**

Lastly, in previous examples I've seen `<gap:plugin name="..." />` as well as `<feature name="...">...</feature>`.

- **Are the `<feature>` tags no longer requried?**

(If this is all easily answered and I am just missing the documentation, please just point me to the docs.)

JD

Comment: a/ I see no use of installing cordova and phonegap both. b/ In docs of Cordova, the config.xml is explained very properly ( [see here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been some changes. As per [Apache Cordova API Docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File):

For projects created with the **Cordova CLI**, this file can be found in the top-level directory:

```
app/config.xml
```

Note that before version 3.3.1-0.2.0, the file existed at **app/www/config.xml**, and that having it here is **still** supported.

When using the CLI to build a project, versions of this file are **passively** copied into various **platforms/ subdirectories**, for example:

```
app/platforms/ios/AppName/config.xml
app/platforms/blackberry10/www/config.xml
app/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml
```

So to your first question:

> Has the second config.xml been removed? If not, why am I not seeing
>   the second config.xml and how do I create it?

Yes the second file is there and can be found in the respective platform folder.

> Am I supposed to be managing everything in the config.xml? If not, why
>   is the config.xml not being updated and what do I need to do to fix
>   it?

I added few plugins and I can see inside **platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.healthapp.edu" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
    </feature>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
</widget>
```

Now if I remove any plugin details then it will NOT be present on that particular platform only. Here I can modify it as per my requirements and i can add/remove **features** or **preferences** as well.

For more details & understanding: 
[Apache Cordova API Docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File)

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's perfect!